# Convert Select to Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL select statement that I need to use to delete the records it finds:

```
SELECT dbo.X_Files.FileID, dbo.X_Files.FileX, dbo.X_ApplyFiles.idPRJ
FROM             dbo.X_Files 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.X_ApplyFiles ON dbo.X_Files.FileID = dbo.X_ApplyFiles.FileID
WHERE  (dbo.X_ApplyFiles.idPRJ IS NULL) 
AND    (dbo.X_Files.FileX = @FileX)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your DBMS?  What table are you trying to delete from?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: which table will you delete from?

Comment: Trying to delete from X_Files all records that are NULL based on not having a match in the X_ApplyFiles table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the table name just after 'delete':

```
delete dbo.X_Files
FROM             dbo.X_Files
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.X_ApplyFiles ON dbo.X_Files.FileID = dbo.X_ApplyFiles.FileID
WHERE  (dbo.X_ApplyFiles.idPRJ IS NULL) 
AND    (dbo.X_Files.FileX = @FileX)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with a `CTE`:

```
;With ToDelete As
(
    SELECT dbo.X_Files.*
    FROM             dbo.X_Files 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.X_ApplyFiles ON dbo.X_Files.FileID = dbo.X_ApplyFiles.FileID
    WHERE  (dbo.X_ApplyFiles.idPRJ IS NULL) 
    AND    (dbo.X_Files.FileX = @FileX)
)
Delete  ToDelete
```

It's also a good way to easily check the records you've selected:

```
;With ToDelete As
(
    SELECT dbo.X_Files.*
    FROM             dbo.X_Files 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.X_ApplyFiles ON dbo.X_Files.FileID = dbo.X_ApplyFiles.FileID
    WHERE  (dbo.X_ApplyFiles.idPRJ IS NULL) 
    AND    (dbo.X_Files.FileX = @FileX)
)
Select    *
From      ToDelete
```

Comment: Won't this delete all the tables?

Comment: @cloudsafe No, only the table selected.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the records with an `ID` that is not found int the `dbo.X_ApplyFiles` table

```
DELETE FROM dbo.X_Files
WHERE dbo.X_Files.FileID NOT IN (SELECT dbo.X_ApplyFiles.FileID FROM dbo.X_ApplyFiles)
```